How can I get column property names in different languages?
Suppose the PC has English and Spanish languages installed.
How do I get the text strings for a property column heading in both English and Spanish?
For example, how could I get the heading text for either the canonical name "System.ItemNameDisplay" or the PKEY_FileName column in both English and Spanish?
Currently, I use PSGetPropertyDescriptionByName() and IPropertyDescription::GetDisplayName() to get the column name from the canonical name. It returns the name in the current language. I can't see how to select the language using a LANGID.
IColumnManager::GetColumnInfo() could give me the column name, but appears to depend on an IShellView object which the program doesn't have. Even if I could use it, I can't see how it would support a LANGID.
I saw a ten year old StackOverflow post, Temporarily change locale settings, implying that temporary changes to the current locale is not the way to go. I suspect this is still true.
I have investigated IPropertStore, and IPropertyStorage, and spent hours searching.
Ideally, I'd implement a function that takes a LANGID and a property, and returns the text value of the property in the given language.

You can just change the thread UI language to the language you need, for example with SetThreadUILanguage function, and use IPropertyDescription::GetDisplayName.
For example this console app sample code:
int main()
{
  CoInitialize(nullptr);

  IPropertyDescription* desc;
  PSGetPropertyDescription(PKEY_FileName, IID_PPV_ARGS(&desc));

  LPWSTR name;
  SetThreadUILanguage(1033);
  desc->GetDisplayName(&name);
  wprintf(L"english: %s\n", name);
  CoTaskMemFree(name);

  SetThreadUILanguage(1036);
  desc->GetDisplayName(&name);
  wprintf(L"french: %s\n", name);
  CoTaskMemFree(name);
  
  desc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}

Will output:
english: Filename
french: Nom de fichier


You might want to suggest spawning a dedicated thread that gathers locale-dependent information to guard against interference with locale-specific calculations on the calling thread.
